# Sqoop / Hive for CCA175: getting table AlreadyExistsException

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, sqoop

I am trying to prepare my CCA175 exam. I am trying to import mysql database `retail_db` to `hive` but getting this error. I tried few times and also removed directories / files from these folders;

```
/user/hive/warehouse
/user/cloudera
```

Still, I am getting this following error, after running this `sqoop` job:

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
--num-mappers 1 \   
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \  
--username=retail_dba \   
--password=cloudera \   
--hive-import \   
--hive-overwrite \   
--create-hive-table \   
--compress \   
--compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \   
--outdir java_files
```

> Logging initialized using configuration in
>   jar:file:/usr/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.7.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   AlreadyExistsException(message:Table categories already exists)

***Any help would be highly appreciated.***

Comment: Add `--verbose` in the end of your command and tell me the hive create table command generated before this error. Ideally it should remove Hive table as overwrite is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you already have categories table in default database of hive. You need to drop tables from Hive. Following are the steps :

1. Login onto mysql and check how many tables does retail_db consists
   of.

   ```
   mysql> use retail_db;   
   mysql> show tables;
   ```
2. Login on hive and check which tables of retail_dba (mysql) do exist?
             Drop tables which exist in hive. In you case, its categories

   ```
   hive> show tables; 

   hive> drop table categories;
   ```
3. Navigate to cloudera home and check whether do you already
           have directories corresponding to these tables. Because as a part of
           Sqoop import to Hive, data is temporarily copied onto HDFS under /user/cloudera/ before moving to hive warehouse location. For
           example, check for categories directory.

   ```
   [cloudera@quickstart /]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/categories
   ```

Comment: delete tables from default db in hive OR create new database in hive and use `--hive-database <new-db-name>` in sqoop job to import tables in specific hive database!

Answer (score 0):

Remove **--create-hive-table** from the sqoop command.

As per sqoop documentation, The job will fail if table with same name already exists.

--create-hive-table If set, then the job will fail if the target hive
table exits. By default this property is false